# How to make toast (method not resloved)

Tags: android, toast

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

why does it say that the **method cannot be resloved**? is it following a *wrong format*?

Comment: replace this with instsnceof Context `Toast.makeText(context, "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Be sure that you have imported the Toast class

2) If it's inside an Activity, your code will work.

3) If it's inside a Fragment, you will need the context to show this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Note Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Context are ::

1-getApplicationContext()

2-classname.this

3-getContext()

4-getActivity()

these are work very good in the different case like Fragment,Activity,.....